# Edition modes design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, programming-languages

I would like to receive ideas about how program edition modes. What I mean is patterns to create an application with different behaviors defined by a selected mode, like those modes in image editors.
Let's exemplify: I have an application that allows me to put blocks and link them together with arrows. So I can use the mode move blocks, the mode delete blocks and or arrows, I can choose create links between blocks, or edit blocks. So my idea is for each type of behavior I want for I choose a button in a toolbar. Clicking in any of the buttons the behavior of the mouse input is treated according to what I need.

Comment: Would be a case of use of Factory Pattern?

Comment: In other words you are trying to emulate the mode behavior in `vim`?

Comment: I think the GOF book would be of great help to you: http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612
Dive into the State/Strategy pattern and tell us how it goes.

Some interesting resources:
http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx
http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx

Comment: With vim you mean Vi Editor? I don't know, I have never used VI...but think it as Photoshop edition mode, like "pen", "eraser", etc.

Comment: Leandro, could you please post a little example of what you are trying to accomplish? Thanks!

Comment: By I have found about state and strategy patterns, It seems that the most apropriated for my case is the state pattern. Strategy pattern seems to use different classes with overriding some methods whereas state pattern the idea is to change the beahavior of the class changing fields of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give my explanation for the example you posted (thanks for that). Let me know if i'm missing something.

I would model an `abstract class Tool` that provides the common protocol that all tools must adhere. This is, a message for modeling the act of using the tool and another for modeling the act of releasing it (just like when you use a pencil, you rest in on a surface, use it and raise it again). Something like `RestOn` and `RaiseUp`.

You'll need to work with the `Element`s under the tool (either `Block`s or `Link`s), and assign a class the responsibility of letting you know wich element is under the tool's pointer. It might be a `Canvas` class.

Then, you can implement specific tool behavior creating an inheritance tree from `Tool` (`Hand Tool`, `EraseTool`, and so on).

For the integration with the Toolbar's buttons i would do the following:
Define a static method/property in the `Tool` class that provides an unique instance of each tool (singleton pattern):

```
abstract class Tool {
    abstract void RestOn...
    abstract void RaiseUp...

    static Tool HandTool() { return _handTool; }
    static Tool EraseTool() { return _eraseTool; }
    ....
}
```

Then in your toolbar's button handlers, you'll have something like

```
btnHandTool_click(...) {
    _canvas.SetActiveTool(Tool.HandTool());
}

btnEraseTool_click(...) {
    _canvas.SetActiveTool(Tool.EraseTool());
}
...
```

The fact that each tool is polimorphycally with respect to the abstract class `Tool` will let you forget about writing specific code to tell if the active tool is a HandTool or an EraseTool instance.
You can view is as changin the strategy (pattern) of the canva's active tool. Internally, the class cannot tell with implementation of the active tool is being used. It only knows about the messages it can respond to.

Lastly but very important, you'll find in the *exelent* book by **Rebecca Wirfs-Brock** named **Designing Object Oriented Software** a chapter dedicated to build a drawing application with it set of tools, showing the different techniques you can use for modelling.
I'll recommend you to grab it and take a look, it really worth the time.

Answer (score 0):

The state pattern is ideally suited for this kind of work.